# Change recordorder in python in loop

Tags: python, loops, recordtype

I wold like iterating over recordtype in loop. And also I want to change its values sometimes.

In dict for instance it is very easy

```
some_dict = {}
for key, value in some_dict.items():
    if not value:
        some_dict[key] = 0
```

I would like to do same in recordtype. 
I tried the following cases:

```
for name in data._fields:
    data[name] = 0
    p = data.__getattribute__(name)
    if not p:
         p = 0
         data.name = 0
```

or

```
for name_field, value in data._asdict().iteritems():
    if not value:
        data = data._replace(name_field=0)
```

And none of them are working..

inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252939/changing-values-of-a-list-of-namedtuples)
I thought it is easy, but what if I do not exactly know what field in recordtype I must change because it depends on if-statement.

So the question is: how to iterate recordtype and after if-statement change some filed ...?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would not use `data.__getattribute__(name)`, use `getattr(data, name)` instead.

Comment: You can use `setattr()` as the mirror to `getattr()` to set attributes dynamically.